# What's the default --master argument for spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark

If I submit my application to spark, without providing "--master" parameter, what will it default to?

Comment: Open `spark-shell`, print spark conf  `spark.sparkContext.getConf.getAll` and see `spark.master` value.

Comment: That's the default for spark-shell, not spark-submit. How do I know they are the same?

Comment: I guess I can do the same when submitting with spark-submit, thanks.

Comment: They are the same... use: `spark-submit --verbose` to see it. (Default: `local[*]`)

Answer (score 2):

By default --master default value is none.

```
Property Name   Default Meaning
spark.master    (none)  The cluster manager to connect to. See the list of allowed master URL's.
```

Please check:: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

The spark-submit script can load default Spark configuration values from a properties file and pass them on to your application. By default, it will read options from conf/spark-defaults.conf in the Spark directory.

Also check valid master options:: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does "none" mean? Will spark work differently if I submit it on my personal laptop vs cluster? What is the default behavior?

Comment: And what will the behavior be?

Comment: what happens when you submit spark JOBS without specifying the option?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. If I submit a spark job on a cluster. Will it run my job on just one node, or will it run it on multiple ones?

Comment: It will read the defaults from conf/spark-defaults.conf that is specified at cluster level.

Comment: And what if nothing is specified there? I have that file, and everything is commented out, but the program still runs.

Comment: It will use a standalone master. spark://HOST:PORT option.

Comment: Do you have any references for that?